# UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE isn't working in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I met a strange problem that in our company's project(let's say project A), I used `UNITY_SAMPLE_TEXCUBE(unity_SpecCube0,i.uvCube)` to sample the default skybox but it always returns black color. On the other hand, if I create a new project(let's say project B) and do the same thing, it returns default skybox's color.

I'm trying to clear the project settings and library of project A, also copying the project B's project settings to project A, however, both of them are not working. I'm confused what caused this issue, any clue?

PS. both projects are in Unity 2018.4.0f1 version

Comment: SpecCube0 returns the nearest reflection probe if present, otherwise the sky set in the render settings. What are the environment reflections set to in your lighting settings?

Comment: default skybox, I've set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amazing thing happened!

I change color space from Gamma space to linear space and then everything works.

Unbelievable!!!

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

1. Go to Window>Rendering>Lighting
2. Check box for Auto Generate (located towards the bottom of the window).

The SkyReflection shader (found here - https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SL-VertexFragmentShaderExamples.html) should now work correctly.